# Extracting + Saving to CSV with Header?

Tags: csv, imacros

Is it possible to, when I save the extracted values in a csv file, add a Header or something in the first row of each column, so it's easier to know what the values refer to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

before beginning to extract with your main macro prepare your file with another one:

```
macro1 = "CODE:";
macro1 += "SET !EXTRACT First<SP>Header,<SP>Second<SP>Header" + "\n";
macro1 += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=U:\imacros FILE=test.csv" + "\n";
ret = iimPlay(macro1);
```

Comment: aw thank you so very much!!! I've been trying Djuggler yesterday, but I must say my preference goes out to iMacros

Answer (score 0):

I just came upon this page looking for an answer to the same question.  I found that I was able to get symbiotech's answer to work if I separated the headers with [EXTRACT] rather than with commas.

```
macro1 = "CODE:";
macro1 += "SET !EXTRACT First<SP>Header[EXTRACT]Second<SP>Header" + "\n";
macro1 += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=U:\imacros FILE=test.csv" + "\n";
ret = iimPlay(macro1);
```